# How to change the animation speed per 'state' in Adobe Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks, animation

I want to know how to alter the animation speed of some text appearing across a banner.  The default is too fast.

**I'm trying to set the duration of time that each state shows for.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched anywhere else for animation speed in Fireworks?

Comment: @Dominic I asked what he tried because a simple Google search on animation Speed in Fireworks easily demonstrates how to do what he's asking. As I understand it, if a simple 'how to' is readily accessible elsewhere then we want to push them in the direction of being self sufficient- this doesn't seem like a problem that the OP wrestled with-- but correct me if I'm wrong, I am relatively new here.

Comment: @Dominic A half second search in Google to find that page and the information is from Adobe. Now if the OP had said something like, 'I looked at Adobe's help page regarding animation states and I don't understand how to manipulate an entire value of speeds for each state' - that question would warrant better help. So asking what someone has tried is a way to encourage a better dialogue on a specific problem they've had as opposed to a 'how to'. I don't understand how asking someone what they've tried is discouraging at all, if anything it encourages better questions and engagement

Comment: Sorry for clogging it up in the comments, your answer makes sense though.

Comment: I'll weigh in a bit here.  I appreciate the discussion.  In the end I found my answer on Adoboe's help section before I relieved dominic's solution.  That being said, it took a little longer and was a bit more frustrating than I'd wished it was.  

I think it's important to have a compendium of easily and well articulated solutions for these small problems as Dominic has imparted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the `States` Panel in the top right, you should see something like this:

[image: CS5 Fireworks States Panel]

Double click where you see the 7, a little box will pop up giving you an option to type in a number, enter a number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to change more than one at the same time, select them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Click, and then double click one of the boxes with a number in it and follow same steps as above.

Here is the [official Adobe section](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00db4b-7f72.html):

> **Set state duration**
>
> The state delay specifies how long the current state is displayed, in hundredths of a second. For example, specify 50 to display the state for half a second or 300 to display it for 3 seconds.
>
> 1. Select one or more states:
>
>    - To select a contiguous range of states, Shift-click the first and last state names.
>    - To select a noncontiguous range of states, hold down Control (Windows) or Command (Mac OS) and click each state name.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Select Properties from the States panel Options menu.
>    - Double-click the State Delay column.
> 3. Enter a value for the state delay.
> 4. Press Enter, or click outside the panel.